# Caml Query returns nothing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

It is my first time using SharePoint. I am trying to add the part that bring a list of last names that start with "br". It is not working and return empty list. I used Fiddler and it returns 500 error.

Here is the query:

```
     "<Where>" +"<And><And><Eq>" +
     "<FieldRef Name='TypeofEvent'/><Value Type='Text'>" + selectedChoice["TypeofEvent"].ToString() + "</Value>" +
    "</Eq>" +
    "<Eq>" +                                                  
 "<FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + aDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "</Value>" +
    "</Eq>" +
"<BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='LastName' /><Value Type='Text'>br</Value></BeginsWith>" +
    "</And></And>" +"</Where>";
```

Is there an error in this code?
Is there any tools that can help me in this business?

Comment: The BIWUG CAML Designer is a great tool, http://www.biwug.be/resources.

Comment: BIWUG CAML Designer could not log in. I am sure the credentials, I am using are correct because I can use them to create new sites and lists through web browser. Is there anything am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax error. Try updated query

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRefName='TypeofEvent'/>
                <ValueType='Text'> + selectedChoice[TypeofEvent].ToString() + </Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRefName='Date'/>
                <ValueType='DateTime'IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'> + aDate.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd) + </Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
        <BeginsWith>
            <FieldRefName='LastName'/><ValueType='Text'> + br + </Value>
        </BeginsWith>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: I tried it and it still returns nothing on the webpage, no error messages either. I wonder if there is something else I can check ?

Comment: As Eric suggested try your CAML query in the tool and see it works